# Sort variables into their own category

Tags: python, list

If I have two sets of lists and I want them to be sorted into their categories. E.g., if I have two lists like below

```
x = ["fruits", "vegetables", "fruits", "meat"]
y = ["apples", "cabbage", "banana", "beef"]
```

and I want them to output like this

```
> fruits
       apples
       banana
  vegetables
       cabbage
  meat
       beef
```

Comment: As with any question in general, and in particular for [homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), you are expected to show what you have tried, and explain what difficulties you have found. Even if you don't know how to solve the problem, can you explain in plain English how would you approach it? What steps you think your program should follow?

Comment: Also, describe how the input and output should be, besides providing an example. For example, can there be more items in one list than in the other? Can items in the second list be repeated?

Comment: How do you think Python will know that a banana is a fruit?

Comment: Hi @IgnatiusReilly I was doing research all night on how to do it, but I really can't find a method that works. There are method of putting into dictionary, then there were sort and set(x+y).  So, the index of x and y correlates to one another, my idea was to merge the duplicates in x... but i don't know how to manipulate it to show that after merging fruits, apples and bananas will correlating with it. Sorry I don't know much coding jargon as I am really just a beginner.

Comment: Hey, those are pretty good ideas! The [solution by Mureinik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73585848/15032126) implements a dictionary as in your first proposal, and the [one by mousetail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73585863/15032126) is merging the duplicates. Consider adding all that that you thought to your question, even if didn't know how to do it, so people doesn't downvote it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd create a `defaultdict` with an empty `list` as the default item, and then iterate over the two lists (e.g., using `zip`) and append each item of `y` to the appropriate `x`:

```py
result = defaultdict(list)
for z in zip(x,y):
    result[z[0]].append(z[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with groupby:

```
import itertools

# Group
for categroy, items in itertools.groupby(
        # groupby requires it to be sorted
        sorted(
            # combine the adjacent elements of both loops
            zip(x,y)),
        # group by the first element
        key=lambda i:i[0]):
    # print the category
    print(category)
    for item in items:
         # print the item
         print(f"\t{item[1]}")
```